# Determining Confidence Probabilities for Distribution

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, lstm

I have a LSTM neural network that predicts the number of items required in each room for the next time step. So for example for room A, B, C and D the model predicts

- A -> 3 items
- B -> 4 items
- C -> 2 items
- D -> 2 items

where all the items are assumed to be of the same type. The problem I have is how to distribute the items across the rooms when the prediction asks for more items then I have available.

**Is there an approach you would suggest where I would be able to determine the distribution based on the confidence level of the number of items in each room?** As an example, using the predicted distribution for the 'rooms' above where the total number of items predicted to be required are 11:

A -> probability 1 item: 0.9,
2 items: 0.8,
3 items: 0.3

B -> probability 1 item: 0.9,
2 items: 0.8,
3 items: 0.8,
4 items: 0.3

C -> probability 1 item: 0.7,
2 items: 0.2

D -> probability 1 item: 0.7,
2 items: 0.7

if I only have 10 items it would be possible to identify that C has the least probability of needing it thus I would be able to distribute as follows:

- A -> 3 items
- B -> 4 items
- C -> **1 item**
- D -> 2 items

Any suggestions or references would be of great help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please explain the data and what is problem domain i.e. Supervised, Unsupervised etc?

Comment: Sure no problem. The data is received as 1hr time steps where in each time step you get an array of 'room' id's. In turn each room id array comes with an integer number of items in that room at the end of the time step, and the number of items that were active/used in that time step. So something like this -> [[[A, 3, 2], [B, 3, 3], [C, 2, 0], [D, 2, 1]],...] with this general representation [[[nodeId, itemsAtStep, activeItemsAtStep], ...], ...]. (Its self-supervised)

Comment: I might also be able to obtain the active time of each item in that 1hr time step as a percentage but ideally this is avoided.